# Send a Notification to a Group of Devices with FCM

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to be able to call a function like this: (from client)

```
void sendNotificationToGroupMembers(String groupId, String message)
```

with a DB Structure like This

```
/userTokens/userId:userInstanceId
/groupMembers/groupId/[userIds...]
/serverRequests/...
```

Now, I after research I think I have an idea on how to approach it, but I don't know if it's the right approach and it is very involved for something I consider should be a very simple task, so I was wondering if there is an easier/simpler way to approach my problem.

This is how I would do it

[Backend]

1. Register ChildEventListener on node `/serverRequets/` inside a Servlet running on a Google Cloud Flexible

[Client]

2. Push to node `/serverRequests/push/groupId:message`

[Backend]

3. Get `/groupMembers/groupId/` and save userIds in a list
4. For each userId, get his userInstanceId in `/userTokens/userId` and save to a list
5. Subscribe every userInstanceId to topic "groupId" using ":batchAdd"
6. Send a notification to topic "groupId"

But I see a problem at steps 4. Because to get the userInstanceId I must make a request with ValueEventListener for each userId, but since they are asynchronous, how do I determine when all the instanceId's have been downloaded? Do I set a timer of 5 seconds? Do I check how large the userId list is, and then use something like LinkedBlockingQueue to publish to a Thread each time an instanceId is downloaded, and only if it reaches the size, do the step 5?

Because I don't find a multiple `.equalTo` query, and I can't download the entire userTokens node...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) for this, not a custom listener you set up. You can see an example of a [notification function here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)

Next, I would consider using [topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), since it would cover the use case you are describing (sending a message to members of a group). I employed this myself and it works a charm.

You flow would now be like this:

- Client tells FCM it would like to subscribe to topic `groupID`.
- At some point there is a message pushed to an endpoint in your `/groupId/messages/` (or however you want to structure it, remember, [denormalization of a NoSQL database is good](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)!)
- Then have a cloud function listen to `/{groupId}/messages/{messageId}` and post a new message to your topic `/groupId`

I hope this makes sense and I understood your question correctly

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will mark accepted should no better answer come up. While I have 0 knowledge of javascript, it seems I will have to learn it to implement the cloud function solution, and after looking at it, it does seem to make things simpler. (AppEngine server solution would cost lots of money). The one thing that is still tricky, is, as you said, client telling to subscribe to topic., because in my case, a admin can add users to a group, and then they would not be subscribed ? Or do I also implement a cloud function for that ?

Comment: I don't know if it's a good practice to have an admin add people to a notification group. But if you really need to do that, just have a client listen to an endpoint in the database, when there is a new key present, the client fetches the key and subscribes to the topic